# Remove "lost" Popup in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

Sometimes in OpenLayers popup bubbles don't disappear or cannot be closed with the x button in the corner, because something went wrong either with the code or the handling of the script or probably both.

Is there any way of referencing those "lost" popups or a method such that  I can get my hands on those folks and make them disappear?

Comment: Hmmm... don't you think it's about time you accepted some of the answers supplied to your previous questions?  If you're not sure what this means or how to do it, please read the FAQ.

Comment: Answers can only be accepted if I can accept them right ?? If i cant accept them , how can i then accept them ?!s

Comment: Did you provide additional comments to your original questions to perhaps solicit more exacting answers.  For example, what are "Popup bubbles"?  Are you referring to dialogs within a particular programming environment?  Editing the questions may help.

Comment: hey guys i changed the computer answers that i think answered my question were checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem codewise. If someone else is experiencing this same problem, here is the cure.

```
function removeLostPopups (layer) 
{         
    var myLayer = layer;    

    for(var i=0; i < myLayer.map.popups.length; i++) {

            myLayer.map.removePopup(layerName.map.popups[i]);
        }
 }
```

I hope that this can help someone in need. The code is self-explanatory.